# sam build when deployed in github now fails

Tags: github, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, sam

Last week I managed to successfully deploy an AWS Lambda function (verified in the AWS console). This morning, I can no longer update the Lambda function. After deleting the Lambda function and pushing changes again, the Lambda was still not able to be created. Instead I get the following traceback:

```
Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - The directory '/github/home/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/github/home/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Invalid requirement: 'Warning: The lock flag'
```

In the workflow deploy file:

```
  - name: Build Lambda image
    run: sam build
```

I don't know exactly what has changed to now cause this error. I tried the flag *--use-container* which successfully moves on the next step of deploying the Lambda image, however there I now encounter further error messages. I'd like to understand why before adding the *--user-container* flag, I didn't encounter this error. Is this *--use-container* flag necessary when not using the sam cli?

**Further info**

Building via the sam cli tool works, not when pushed via the Github actions workflow.

Comment: Same thing happened to my repo, even though I haven't modified any dependencies. Note that in my casegit the error pertains to the environment created by github actions, not the requirements for the code itself. `Virtualenv location: /home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs`

Comment: @MarcMaxmeister: thanks for the heads up. Did you resolve this by policies in the template.yml or something else?

Comment: It is working today (24 hours later) and appears to be some github bug that they didn't bother to report on their uptime page.